# Why does this for loop only display one image on the jFrame?

Tags: java, imageicon

The image is only displayed once from the loop, instead of the six it is supposed to.

This is for a dice game, where the image is randomly chosen to simulate the dice rolling.

```
public void image(int s1, int s2){
        String[] pics = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"};
        Random rand1 = new Random();
        for( int x = 0; x<6; x++){
            int pic1 = rand1.nextInt(6)'
            ImageIcon die1 = new ImageIcon("images/"+pics[pic1]+".jpg");
            diceImage.setIcon(die1);
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
                null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

This for loop is supposed to repeat six times, randomly choosing and displaying an image on a jFrame through a jLabel. When the method is called, the method waits for the three seconds without displaying the image, only at the end is an image displayed.

Comment: You seem to call this method from an event listener (that is why the UI is blocked for 3 seconds). While this method is running the event dispatch thread is blocked and cannot redraw the UI. For hints read the Swing documentation about multithreading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: This is not all the relevant code, there are references to other variables not defined here.

Comment: Try diceImage.rePaint or yourJFrame.rePaint before sleeping.

Comment: @ThomasKläger you're a saint mate, works like a dream now. Thank you so much